# Spring MVC @Controller creates empty response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, response, is-empty

I'm trying to build a REST-Api with Spring MVC 4.0.4-RELEASE. The application consists of multiple maven modules like domain, service, etc...

When I run the webapp in my browser, and make an request to api/test, I expect a String as a response. But the response i always emtpy with a http status 200, in browser, as well a in curl. But It doesn't work with JSON and Jackson2 in my classpath too.

It seems, that that the method ping() never gets invoked, but the request handling seems to be ok..?!

```
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/api/test]
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /test
DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String api.resource.TestResource.ping()]
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/api/test] is: -1
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

There's also a handler interceptor, that never gets invoked too, because it seems that spring doesn't "jump" into the handler method...

Here's the code of my @Controller an web configuration:

```
@Controller
public class TestResource {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ping() {
        LOG.debug("Request received.");
        final Account account = new Account.Builder("m@m.de", "123456", new Date(), new Role.Builder("Role_USER").build()).build();
        return account.toString();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "api.resource" })
public class ApiConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestTimeProcessingInterceptor());
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }
}


public class ApiInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { EventingConfig.class, RepositoryConfig.class, MailConfig.class, ServiceConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { ApiConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
    }
}
```

This seems like a valid configuration for me, because there are no problems running the app via maven and embedded tomcat7 or Eclpse WTP.
I guess there's a very simple solution, but unfortunately I can't see it at this moment..

So I am grateful for any ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `/api` coming from in the mapping?

Comment: check whether Request received. log gets printed in log file, if printed then method has been called..why you have doubt about it when you use logger..

Comment: @geoand: /api is my context root in this case. the mapping seems to be ok, because there is no 404 error on /api/test, and the log output above indicates, that the correct handler method is found.

Comment: @Karibasappa G C: the request is received (log above), but the method not invoked, because there is no expected log output.

Comment: are you converting that object to some format using converter ?

Comment: No..The handler method is just expected to return a string for test purposes. So I don't use any converters, because in my opinion this isn't neccessary?! I got that working in another context a few month ago, without explicitly converting objects.

Comment: Are you sure logging is not turned off or it's not logging somewhere else?  Do you have the ability to put a break in the code via IDE?

Comment: Logging is definitely not turned off. When I set a breakpoint in my controller method, the app doesn't stop at that point, because it doesn't step into the ping() method..?!